# Facebook login dialog disappears soon after loading without login screen or any response in Android App

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, sdk, fbconnect

Facebook sdk is integrated to our android app and fb signin was working fine till  last week. From 22nd May however, in some devices like LG-P500, huawei-u8800 running 2.2 android OS - when clicked on fbconnect login button ,the login dialog opens and closes in short time with out waiting for user input. However the same code is working in devices like Samsung-S5570.
Due to this, we cannot even use the app.

When I debug the app, the facebook error message is shown as 'The connection to the server was unsuccessful.'.

Comment: Please see my answer and if my answer was helping you then accept it.

Answer (score 0):

change your Main Java File code and write down following code:-

```
public void loginAndPostToWall() {
    facebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH,
            new LoginDialogListener());
}
```